# Create a template mechanism in Objective-C for iPad applications

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm looking for a solution to create a sort of template in Objective C. I'll try to explain my problem.
I would create a sort of main view which has 1 side bar that remain always visible. This side bar have controls. The main view is responsible to load a Navigation Controller (UINavigationController seems to be ok) that manages other views. When switching a view to another, the sidebar always remain visible under the Navigation Controller and its views.
Through the controls of the sidebar, it's possible to send event to a specific view loaded by the Navigation Controller.

Any idea to create a similar template?

Thank you. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a splitview which is implemented by UISplitViewController.